# Correct distribution to model proportion of time in a day

Tags: poisson-distribution, glmm, poisson-regression, beta-distribution, beta-regression

I would like to determine how the presence of researchers influenced the amount of time that shorebirds spent on the nest in a day. My data consists of proportions that range from 0.715-0.997, which are the number of minutes the birds spent on the nest in one day/the number of minutes in one day (1440). Do I consider as count data since I am counting the number of minutes in a day? In that case is the appropriate distribution to analyze this data poisson? Or is this type of data considered continuous proportions that would require an analysis using a beta distribution? I plan on using SAS glimmix to analyze this data set.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that beta regression makes more sense: it naturally handles the [0,1] range, while treating it as a count straightforwardly doesn't account for the top-end limitation of your [0,1440] range.

Comment: +1. More importantly, IMO, the underlying time is continuous and not discrete. The upper limit could be addressed by using a binomial distribution but it wouldn't make much sense to assume that the birds decided independently for each of the 1440 minutes with a certain probability whether to spend it in the nest or not. Possibly the data even look normal enough?